# JavaScript Split from comma separated to array list with values

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is from a comma separated text (like this one):

```
hello,test,ciao
```

Get a javascript array with a predetermined value.
I know how to split a comma-separated list, but I don't know how to add a value inside them.

Actual code:

### **HTML**

```
  <input onkeyup="test()" type="text" id="origin">
  <div id="response">

  </div>
```

### **JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function getValue(){
  var returnV = $("#origin").val();
  return returnV
}
function test(){
    var origin = getValue();
    var array = origin.split(',');
    console.log(array)
}
```

### **OUTPUT**

```
["hello", "test", "ciao"]
```

---

### **WHAT I'M TRYING TO GET**

```
{
  "hello":"predetermined value",
  "test":"predetermined value",
  "ciao":"predetermined value",
}
```

I think this question is interesting because this way yo can, for example, create new configurations with a starter value and add custom confirgurations for each of them later. I know that the split part is already replied on stackoverflow, what I'm having trouble with is with adding the default values :), thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what is `predeterminated value` for each ?

Comment: So start with your array, and then loop through it adding properties to an object.

Comment: @PriyeshKumar I need to create for them an starter configuration, predeterminated value was an example.

Comment: @MattBurland looks good, do you know a post on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't want to change your code so much. just have a look up to object creation.

```js
function getValue(){
  return document.getElementById("origin").value
}
function test(){
    var obj = {}
    var origin = getValue();
    origin.split(", ").forEach(function(e) {
        obj[e] = "predeterminated value";}
   );
   console.log(obj);
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="test()" type="text" id="origin">
  <div id="response">

  </div>
```

Comment: glad  to help you -))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iterating over the array? Like this:

```
function getValue(){
  var returnV = $("#origin").val();
  return returnV
}
function test(){
    var origin = getValue();
    var object = {}
    var array = origin.split(',');
    array.forEach((item) => {
      object[item] = "predeterminated value" 
    }
    console.log(object)
}
```

A couple notes: try to give more meaningful names to your variables; the word is "predetermined",

Comment: I'm going to try this now, sorry, I'm spanish btw xD

Comment: @QUIQUELHAPPY no worries!

Answer (score 0):

Store your output to a variable:

```
var output=["hello", "test", "ciao"]
```

Then do something like this with it:

```
var newObject={};

for(var i in output){
 var property=output[i];
 newObject[property]='predeterminated value';
}
```

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebf50j94/1/) (open console to see result)

Answer (score 0):

Split your string and then use `Array.prototype.reduce` to build an object from it.

```js
var original = "hello,test,ciao";

var obj = original.split(',').reduce(function(p,c) {
    p[c] = "predeterminated value";
    return p;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

It's not exactly clear where `predeterminated value` is supposed to come from. If it's the same for all properties of your object, then this will work as-is. If it's not, you'll have to figure out how to select the right value.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to use this only for creating a starter configuration for a group of values, this will work perfectly. +1 for the code snippet! I'll accept your question now :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can follow the below code snippet this will help

```js
function getValue(){
    var returnV = 'hey,your,input,keys,goes,here';
    return returnV;
}
    
function test(){
  var origin = getValue();
  var array = origin.split(',');
  var finalObj = {};
  var defaultVal = 'pre-def';
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      finalObj[array[i]] = defaultVal;
  }
  console.log("arry",array)
  console.log("converted",finalObj)
}
test();
```